# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\customer' not found Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
<?php
        namespace App\Http\Controllers;
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;
        use App\Http\Controllers\customer;
        use App\Http\Requests;

        class CustomerController extends Controller
        {
        public function index()
        {
        return view('insert');
        }
        public function create()
        {

        }
        public function store(Request $request)
        {

        $customer = new customer;
        $customer->name = $request->name;
        $customer->sex = $request->sex;
        $customer->pob = $request->pob;
        $customer->tel = $request->tel;
        $customer->email = $request->email;
        $customer->save();
        }


         public function show()
           {

        return view('show');


           }
        }
?>
```

I m getting error as **Class 'App\Http\Controllers\customer' not found Laravel 5.2**.
I have use App\customer;
use Inputs;
Why am I getting error ?
What is the problem in the code?

Answer (score 2):

If your `customer` class is in `App` namespace, you need to use:

```
use App\customer;
```

instead of

```
use App\Http\Controllers\customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple You need to understand. Make sure you have created a model Customer.php in app/Customer.php and another important thing you must create your table with customers that's all. After that you need to add this line before class  like:-

```
use App\Customer;
```

Hope it helps :)